# Transform ES6 module format to ES5.1, with minimal pollution of global scope

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, rollup

I'm working on a project where I am required to implement specific function interfaces (which handle binary to JSON transcoding).  The JS code is uploaded to a web server which states that it runs ECMAScript 5.1.  There are at least two different modules which currently share some common code (currently just duplicated between files).

I've already implemented the code, its not complex but a little more than trivial, as there are about a dozen payloads with half a dozen fields in each that need bit-packing etc to convert from binary to JSON and back.  I can modularise some of the bigger switch statements into sub-functions, but every function ends up in the file scope, not to mention the source modules end up quite long.  File scope in this instance, in the target environment, is 'global' and so I'm a little worried about polluting the scope with symbols (even if it might work ok, it just smells bad).

Ideally I'd like to break functionality out into separate modules, and take advantage of some later ES6 constructs, such as arrow functions, spread etc.  In addition, I have unit tests which run in NodeJS environment (Jest), so the source module needs exports so I can import it into tests.  To achieve that and keep the module compatible with ES5.1 I have to add a bit of conditional code to the end of the file to make it work as a CommonJS file, thus:

```
if (module !=== undefined) {
  module.exports.foo = foo;
  module.exports.bar = bar;
}
```

So far so good.

I've explored whether I can use Babel to transpile the code from ES6 to ES5, and in principle this works ok.  I've also explored how to combine the source modules (I've tried with both Webpack and Rollup) and get quite close to something that doesn't look like code-soup.

In both Webpack and Rollup cases, I don't seem to have the option of having the specific needed global functions, and everything else hidden from global scope somehow (IIFE, object literals as namespaces or perhaps symbol prefixes based on module name).

Of course, depending on the ES6 features used, polyfills are injected to provide that functionality, and I don't need those in the global scope either.

To give an example of the source and the output, consider the following:

```
// foo.js
import { fooHelper } from './fooHelper'
export function foo() {
  // aribitrary complexity involving fooHelper
  fooHelper()
}

// bar.js
import { barHelper } from './barHelper'
export function bar() { 
  // aribitrary complexity involving barHelper
  barHelper()
}
```

Pseudo-output:

```
// Object literal so there is only one symbol added to the global context aside from
// the expected entry points.  This could equally be IIFE or some such outputting
// outputting to a single symbol.

var myNamespace = {
  fooHelper: function fooHelper() {
    // implementation from fooHelper.js
  },
  barHelper: function barHelper() {
    // implementation from barHelper.js
  }
}

function foo() {
  myNamespace.fooHelper();
}

function bar() {
  myNamespace.barHelper();
}

if (module !=== undefined) {
  module.exports.foo = foo;
  module.exports.bar = bar;
}
```

The above shows how I would code it by hand, but I'm curious if there is a webpack/rollup config that achieves the same thing.  This would give me the modularity, allow me to share code between separate modules, and give me some syntactic sugar that keeps my brain from having to remember what works in ES5.1 vs 6.

Because this is a bit of a non-standard target, I don't seem to be having much luck finding examples for webpack or rollup that aren't assuming a browser or Node type environment, or to suggest how I might add something to an existing config that does something like I need.

Transforming would theoretically allow me to have an output for testing, and an output for production, so I don't need to include the CommonJS shim in the production, not that its an onerous overhead.  Ideally any polyfills should be also namespaced so they aren't polluting the global environment.

In my trials with Webpack and Rollup, I either ended up with all the modules combined into the global scope, or wrapped in an IIFE that failed to expose the required entry points at global scope, other than via the module.exports (which the target doesn't understand, it needs the function(s) at file scope).

I don't need minification of the output, but it should be as readable as possible (ideally carrying over comments which contain JSDoc blocks that describe types and the JSON formats that act as input and output).

I don't think its worth the effort of implementing a plugin, which seems to be the way to go if there isn't something 'out-of-the-box'.  I don't really have enough experience of Webpack or similar to know where to look for a solution, and my experiments so far only go to about 80% with the last 20% being non-trivial.

Apologies if any of the terminology I've used is misleading, its a bit of a minefield ;-)

Comment: On one hand, this question makes total sense. The web module space is cluster**** of 25+ years of legacy constraints, questionable design decisions, workarounds that became de facto standards, and general cruft. OTOH this question makes no sense: write whatever you want, compile it with babel, and bundle it with rollup into a single file and call it a day. This is a solved problem, no pollution of global scope at all. Your conditional check is trying to reimplement part of what the tooling already does. Also, you say server running a specific version of ES, are we talking node.js or the web?

Comment: @JaredSmith My point being that what I've tried does not yield the final suggested result in respect to which symbols ARE in the global scope.  What the bundle represents IS a module, which works in respect to my Node test environment, but does not satisfy the requirement of the production environment.  I don't know what the server environment is, I just know it runs JS code and expects certain symbols (function signatures) to be global.  It's a black box with these requirements. I get that it makes no sense, its somewhat academic at this point.

Comment: @JaredSmith With respect to the conditional check, because CJS provides a global 'module', you can just assign to it.  In this environment, no such symbol exists, hence the check

Comment: "[It] expects certain symbols (function signatures) to be global" it's unclear what you mean by this, do they need to be available in the global scope, i.e. calling `foo()` in a different file without a ReferenceError, or able to be required by another module `const foo = require('foo')`? "CJS provides a global 'module'... in this environment, no such symbol exists" *what* environment? Is this a custom Javascript runtime? Again, nothing about this makes sense, please provide appropriate details! This is a very unusual situation. Best guess is that somebody embedded JS as a scripting language..

Comment: ...in another application and needs you to script it but that's just a guess and without more details around the situation we probably won't be able to help you with it because we don't know how many of our assumptions about normal everyday JS development actually hold. I'm sorry to say this is probably going to require some exploratory coding on your part to figure out what works and what doesn't. Next thing to try is compile w/babel, bundle with rollup, but attach the things you want global explicitly to the global object: `global.whatever = whatever`. It may not be called 'global':

Comment: `var globalObject = this;` at the top-level scope of a file will usually suffice but if not try `var globalObject = new Function('return this');` which is a workaround that *usually* works. Good luck!

Comment: @JaredSmith  I think I was clear in my example what was needed.  Specified function signatures at file scope.  As a variant, or conditionally, they need to be assigned to module.exports, to satisfy the requirement to support testing in Jest.  The server is TTN, and the docs are here (https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/integrations/payload-formatters/javascript/) - see the notes at the top which describe the runtime environment (albeit minimally).  I know for a fact that 'module' is undefined, which is why I had already made that conditional.  I suspect they 'eval()' the source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242821/discussion-between-dave-meehan-and-jared-smith).